# django forms - getting django to build the form you want

Tags: django, forms, renderer

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    def as_custom_table(self):
        "Returns this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row = u'<tr%(html_class_attr)s><td class="label_col">%(label)s</td><td class="field_col">%(field)s%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
            error_row = u'<tr><td colspan="2" class="error">%s</td></tr>',
            row_ender = u'</td></tr>',
            help_text_html = u'<br />%s',
            errors_on_separate_row = True)
```

I'm trying to see if I can get django to do the heavy lifting and render a form in the way I want it to render.

The problem here is, there might be one or two fields that need to render slightly differently. Such as a "please confirm you agree to our terms and conditions" check box, which would need to span two columns.

Also some other things, such as error placement, might need changing.

I could override the _html_output method to change error placement, but what about getting an individual field to use a different render method?

I think ultimately I need to revert to manually building the form html in the template, but I'm just wondering how much of it Django could do for me with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [suggested method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) will be to use a template like this:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

You can conditionally override specific fields using [`{{ if field.my_property }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#if).

Comment: Wonder if it's possible to do this in the actual django template renering engine/